# Something like #ifdef to let me not add all libs to my projects

Tags: java

I have a set of services that are provided through jar files (they are ad networks). I wnat to just add the networks I need for every project but have all code that handles the networks in just a class (It is called AdNetworkManager). For example with c# this is easily done having some symbols definined true or false and just wrap every ad network code with a #ifdef / #endif statements. Is this possible with java?

I have read about having some static final constants but this does not work the way I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to ignore `import` directive in some cases? Did I correctly get your question?

Comment: There is no analogy for #ifdef in java. Why don't you feed a property into your java app, and make it behave differently based onthat? See System.getProperty(). If you want to exclude those classes from the build, then see how to use maven profiles.

Comment: @vikingsteve : Well, I think this won't solve the problem. First, I need to have an import to use that lib, and second there would be code in the project that dependsd on a package that can't be imported because its related lib has not been added to the project. The main point is to strip out code when a condition is met (it is a pity there's not #ifdef counterpart.

Comment: @zvzdhk : not just the imports but all the code related with this import too.

Comment: define an interface, implement 2 concrete classes (one using your lib, one not using it) and put in some properties what class you'll instantiate at runtime, via Class.forName(String).

Comment: This could be feasible if I had just two combinations. But I have around 5 or 6 ad networks at the moment. With your method I would have to create a lot of combinations. One solution I have thought is to create a lib for every ad network with its manament code, but his is not what I want. I would like to have all management code in one class

Comment: 6 or 10 is a manageable number of specializations. If they share common code you can have one or more base classes (always implementing the interface) and inherit from them and then specialize when needed. It's more code, I agree, but is still better than adding countless if/else in your code.

Comment: @BigMike, he doesn't want to add sources of your suggested interface realizations

Comment: Keep in mind that an import of an unavailable type does not itself cause any runtime errors. In Java, imports are only about simple name resolution. If you never refer to a class at runtime, no attempt will be made to load it.

Comment: Didn't know that. Anyway the problem persists. The need to strip out the code that uses the classes that have not been included in the build paths.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use property files? You can find simple example etc. [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)